# UIView.animation not animating colour change

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

My animation is not actually smoothing the colour change. Here is my code:

```
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 3.0,
    animations: { () -> Void in
        myLabel!.backgroundColor! = UIColor(
            red: 1.0,
            green: 1.0,
            blue: 1.0,
            alpha: 1.0
        )
    },
    completion: nil
)
```

This code is wrapped in an `if` statement, which in turn is inside a function. `myLabel` is the only parameter; and it's of type `UILabel?`

My app has a `UILabel` with a pan gesture. When the user swipes up, the colour should change. If the background colour (which is another label) is black, `myLabel` should animate becoming white. (This is the `if` statement)

I've had this same problem multiple times in my app and it's the same code each time.
There's no error, but no animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code

```
 UIView.transition(with: myLabel, duration: 0.4, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        self.myLabel.backgroundColor! = UIColor.init(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }) { (finish) in
    }
```